# WebRTC video chat with Ajax instead of WebSocket: Possible?

Tags: php, ajax, websocket, webrtc

About six months ago, I was able to successfully code my own WebSocket server script in PHP. Through that, I was able to set up a WebRTC video chat service on my local host. I was quite happy until I realized that in order to deploy it, I needed a web server that gave me access to sockets.

Unfortunately, no shared web hosting allows for sockets and all web servers that offer sockets are expensive. While not an effective solution on a large scale, for the sake of setting up a demo to show people, I want to change the signalling method over from WebSocket to Ajax so that I can show off the WebRTC video chat service I made.

To that end, I've been trying to code something for the past few days, but have had no success in getting the WebRTC peers to capture each other's video.

At the moment, when one client connects to the script, I am using Ajax to send a request to a PHP script that checks whether there are any other active users in the DB. If not, the script then creates an offer, and places the offer in the DB. After that, the client polls a separate PHP script every second to check for an answer from another client connecting to the script.

After that, I then connect to the script from another client, which queries the same PHP script and DB, which then realizes that an active user (the first connection) has already posted an offer, which the second client acquires and sets for the remote description. The second client then creates an answer, which is placed in the DB.

At this point, the first client (which is polling the DB every second) detects that an answer is present and sets that answer as the remote description for the first client. Unfortunately, even after successfully doing all of this, the other client's video isn't popping up.

So here's where I'm confused and have three (multipart) questions:

1) I thought that after both clients set their local description and then sent that local description to the other client and the other client set that received description as the remote description that the onaddstream event was supposed to fire, thus allowing me to display the remote video. However, this isn't happening. This worked fine before when I used WebSocket, but it's not working at all with pure Ajax. Is there something in particular I'm missing? Has the WebRTC spec changed radically in the past six months? I've tried looking at the WebRTC specs, but I don't see any major changes.

2) After getting frustrated with not getting things to work with Ajax, I went back to my WebSocket version and loaded it on my local host. I haven't changed the code at all since last using it (which worked fine six months ago), but now, when I try to use it, sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes I get errors related to not being able to set the local and/or remote descriptions. What's up with this? Have there been changes to the specs that would cause this to happen? Related to this, even though I can't get the remote videos to pop up with the Ajax version, I have been echoing a lot of stuff out to the console, and it seems like with the Ajax version as well, sometimes the local and remote descriptions for both clients are successfully set up, and sometimes errors occurs when trying to set the local/remote descriptions for whatever reason, even though I'm running the exact same script each time without any changes. I'm using the latest version of Chrome, and I'm starting to wonder if there's a bug it in or something.

3) Is the onicecandidate event handler required to establish a connection? My assumption was that peers could establish a connection with simply a valid offer and answer, and that the onicecandidate event was use to provide alternate routes, etc., which could lead to a better connection (but aren't required). Am I wrong? If the onicecandidate info is required, how do you recommend I handle this with Ajax as the signalling method?

I know that's a lot of info and a lot of questions, but any information/insight that anyone can offer would be very much appreciated. I've been banging my head against my desk for the past couple of days trying to figure this out, and nothing is making sense.

Comment: "all web servers that offer sockets are expensive" You can get what you need for free during one year with Amazon Web Services, I'd say Google App Engine too, but I'm not sure on this one.

Comment: Antoine, that's good to know. Thank you very much. Unfortunately, it doesn't really answer the main questions I had though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My first advice about your app. working/not working sporadically is to look at current online working implementations. There are plenty of WebRTC demos on the Internets.

### AJAX

About AJAX: why wouldn't it work? I am currently working on just the same thing as you and it works fine *everytime* (I cannot disclose the source for the moment). Clients are constantly polling the server at regular intervals and they can send SDP descriptions/ICE candidates to a specific other client that way. The server acts as a simple bridge (this is the basis of signalling).

Be it WebSocket, AJAX or [IPoAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers), as long as you transfer to the other client everything he needs (and at the right moment, more on this later), it should work. I even made a demo where you manually copy/paste the SDP description and ICE candidates using text areas and click on buttons to move forward in the signalling process and that, of course, worked fine too.

### ICE candidates

Now: yes, you need ICE candidates. Look at a sample **SDP offer** chunk I just generated using `createOffer` on Chromium 27:

```
v=0
o=- 3866099361 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS 9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 107 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:l8Qu31Vu4VG5YApS
a=ice-pwd:TpyQ5iESUH4HvYGE4ay8JUhe
a=ice-options:google-ice
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=mid:audio
a=rtcp-mux
a=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:bC5YSe2xCmui0wSxUHWKIi9INbZ2y0VrO1swoZbl
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:107 CN/48000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:1976175890 cname:/+lKYsttecoiyiu5
a=ssrc:1976175890 msid:9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8 9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8a0
a=ssrc:1976175890 mslabel:9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8
a=ssrc:1976175890 label:9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8a0
m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:l8Qu31Vu4VG5YApS
a=ice-pwd:TpyQ5iESUH4HvYGE4ay8JUhe
a=ice-options:google-ice
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=sendrecv
a=mid:video
a=rtcp-mux
a=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:bC5YSe2xCmui0wSxUHWKIi9INbZ2y0VrO1swoZbl
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack 
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc:3452335690 cname:/+lKYsttecoiyiu5
a=ssrc:3452335690 msid:9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8 9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8v0
a=ssrc:3452335690 mslabel:9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8
a=ssrc:3452335690 label:9kTlKaNe1exIs6JgEFYfXlu6E5f4B5R3I2D8v0
```

Do you see anything that could help another client connect to my machine? I don't think so. The purpose of all this ICE mechanism is to gather connection candidates (local ones like `192.168.1.15`, "public" ones (the public IP assigned by your ISP) using STUN if you're behind any NAT that's not symmetrical, or TURN ones for symmetrical NATs).

Upon receiving those ICE candidates, the other peer will order them using some predefined metrics for prioritizing and then issue connection tests to find a good candidate. So please share them: the other peer needs them (and you need its too).

So here are some of my ICE candidates:

```
a=candidate:303249700 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.50.238 43806 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:303249700 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.50.238 43806 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1552991700 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.50.238 35630 typ host generation 0
```

Now those are concrete (albeit only local, because I didn't configure the RTC peer connection with any STUN URL) ways for another peer to connect to my machine.

### WebRTC signalling tips

There are a few interesting tips on the bottom of [this page](https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/docs/webrtc-for-beginners.html). I honnestly could not tell you right now why you should follow those or why they exist in the first place, but I did follow them and had no signalling problems. Here they are:

1. For answerer: NEVER add ICE candidates until that peer generates/creates answer SDP
2. Stop adding ICE candidates when remote stream starts flowing
3. Don't create peer connection for answerer until you get offer SDP

You can manage all that on the client side by having some WebRTC finite-state machine. Please see the referenced page to understand what he means by *remote stream starts flowing*.

Try to share ICE candidates and add them at the opposite side and at least follow tips #1 and #3 and your application should work again.

### Signalling communication

You asked how to transfer an ICE candidate from a peer to another one in the event of ICE candidates being important to share (which they are). To share things using AJAX, whatever those things are, you can use mailboxes. I believe you're already doing this by placing what is due for a client in the database.

Whenever a peer needs to send something to another one, send it ASAP (using AJAX). On the server side, place this "mail" in the destination client's mailbox. When a peer (periodically) polls the server for new mails, give it all its new mails.

When an SDP offer is created, ICE candidates are quickly generated. All those ICE candidates and the SDP description will probably get into the destination mailbox within a few milliseconds. There are good chances that the destination peer will poll everything neede at once. Even if an ICE candidate arrives late, its next polling will get it.

Comment: eepp, this is a really great answer. Thank you so much. I think you answered all of my questions perfectly. I'm going to mark this as the right answer, but before I do, I just want to test out everything you suggested first. After I get it working (which I think I can), I will respond in kind and mark your answer as correct. Thanks a lot. This is a really great answer. (Did I already say that?!)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really answer your questions, but for a signalling server you might want to take a look at [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) (on Node). I wrote a codelab explaining how to set this up:[bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab). It's very straightforward -- the complete example is [here](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab/src/6daf0496dc78e1704cb9b71b9e897e829a347561/complete/step6?at=master): the signalling server code is about 50 lines.

[SimpleWebRTC](https://github.com/henrikjoreteg/SimpleWebRTC) runs the [Signalmaster](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster) server, which uses Socket.io.

(Robert Nyman wrote a good [blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/03/making-webrtc-simple-with-conversat-io/) explaining this.)

Another option is to use XHR with the Google Channel API, as per the [apprtc.appspot.com](http://apprtc.appspot.com) example: code [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/js/apprtc).

Comment: Sam, I looked at all those links. Very interesting. Thanks. If I'm on a shared web hosting plan with just a basic Apache server, is it possible to install Node.js, or is that something that depends on the web hosting company? On a side note, what do you think is the best way to determine which client should send the offer, and which client should wait for the offer before sending an answer? I've never really understood the best way to handle that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whether or not Node.js is available or can be installed depends on your hosting company. There are lots of Node providers such as Nodejitsu, Joyent, Heroku, EngineYard and Nodester.  It doesn't really matter which client sends the offer -- whoever gets there first! Socket.io rooms work well for this -- you can see this in my codelab example.

Comment: Sam, thanks again for your reply. I looked at your example code, but I'm still a bit confused by how it's determined who gets there first. Or I should say, that makes sense, but do you first check whether there are any other clients in the room, and if there aren't, then create the offer, or do you just blindly create the offer on every client no matter what, and then after the fact, check for other clients, and decide whether to use the offer accordingly? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: The first client in the room will wait until another client enters the room and then make an offer: the first client gets a message from the server app that it's the first in the room and thereby knows it's the initiator (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

Any way of sending messages should work equivalently.  It might help to keep in mind that are only about 4 basic messages you want to exchange:

1. notification that a peer has joined (or left)
2. an offer message ==> `SetRemoteDescription` with it, then make an answer & send it
3. an answer message ===> `SetRemoteDescription` with it
4. an ice candidate sent from the other peer ==> call `addIceCandidate` with it

The ice candidate thing is the strange part.  Also, the candidate object contains funny characters, so when you send it, URI encode it.  In Coffeescript, mine looks something like:

```
peer_connection.onicecandidate = (e) ->
   send { 
          line_index: e.candidate.sdpMLineIndex
          candidate: encodeURIComponent(e.candidate.candidate) }
```

eepp's answer is good, but it contains some advice I don't think is correct.  Specifically, these 3 tips I believe are all incorrect:

> - For answerer: NEVER add ICE candidates until that peer
>     generates/creates answer SDP
> - Stop adding ICE candidates when remote
>     stream starts flowing
> - Don't create peer connection for answerer until
>     you get offer SDP

Here is a sequence of events I have working today (Feb 2014) in Chrome.  This is for a simplified case where peer 1 will stream video to peer 2.

1. Set up some way for the peers to exchange messages.  (The variance in how people accomplish this is what makes different WebRTC code samples so incommensurable, sadly.  But mentally, and in your code organization, try to separate this logic out from the rest.)
2. On each side, set up message handlers for the important signalling messages.  You can set them up and leave them up.  There are 4 core messages to handle & send:

   - other peer joined
   - an ice candidate sent from the other side ==> call `addIceCandidate` with it
   - an offer message ==> `SetRemoteDescription` with it, then make an answer & send it
   - an answer message ===> `SetRemoteDescription` with it
3. On each side, create a new peerconnection object and attach event handlers to it for important events: onicecandidate, onremovestream, onaddstream, etc.

   - ice candidate ===> send it to other side
   - stream added ===> attach it to a video element so you can see it
4. When both peers are present and all the handlers are in place, peer 1 gets a trigger message of some kind to start video capture (using the `getUserMedia` call)
5. Once `getUserMedia` succeeds, we have a stream.  Call `addStream` on the peer 1's peer connection object.
6. Then -- and only then -- peer 1 makes an offer
7. Due to the handlers we set up in step 2, peer 2 gets this and sends an answer
8. Concurrently with this (and somewhat obscurely), the peer connection object starts producing ice candidates.  They get sent back and forth between the two peers and handled (steps 2 & 3 above)
9. Streaming starts by itself, opaquely, as a result of 2 conditions:

   - offer/answer exchange
   - ice candidates received, exchanged, and added

I haven't found a way to add video after step 9.  When I want to change something, I go back to step 3.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Ajax example which will share ICE and SDP without socket.io or anything else. This might be useful

> The backend source code is published [in this repository](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/node-webrtc-ajax)

```
<span></span>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="./peer-to-peer.js"></script>
<script>
    (async function(global) {

        const root = document.querySelector('#root');
        const span = document.querySelector('span');
        const peerHub = new Map();

        global.peerHub = peerHub;

        const sleep = (timeout = 1000) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(), timeout));

        const createVideo = (stream) => {
            const video = document.createElement('video');
            video.srcObject = stream;
            root.appendChild(video);
            video.play();
        };

        const request = async (url = '', params = {}) => {
            const builder = new URL(url, location.origin);
            Object.entries(params).forEach(([k, v]) => builder.searchParams.set(k, v));
            const data = await fetch(builder.toString());
            const json = await data.json();
            return json;
        };

        const currentStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: { 
                facingMode: 'user',
                width: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: window.screen.width,
                },
                height: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: window.screen.height,
                },
            },
        });

        const currentUserId = await request('api/join-room');
        span.innerText = `Joined as user_${currentUserId}`;
        createVideo(currentStream);

        const createConnection = (toUserId = -1, initiator = false) => {
            const p2p = new PeerToPeer({
                mediaStream: currentStream,
                fromUserId: currentUserId,
                initiator,
                toUserId,
            });
            p2p.on('stream', ({ stream }) => createVideo(stream));
            p2p.on('sdp', ({ sdp, toUserId }) => {
                console.log(`Outgoing sdp ${toUserId} ${Date.now()}`, { sdp });
                request('api/create-sdp', {
                    currentUserId,
                    toUserId,
                    sdp,
                });
            });
            p2p.on('ice', ({ ice, toUserId }) => {
                console.log(`Outgoing ice ${toUserId} ${Date.now()}`, { ice });
                request('api/create-ice', {
                    currentUserId,
                    toUserId,
                    ice,
                });
            });
            peerHub.set(toUserId, p2p);
            return p2p;
        };

        const userList = await request('api/user-list');
        const targetList = userList.filter((id) => id !== currentUserId);
        targetList.forEach((toUserId) => createConnection(toUserId, true));

        const browseForIncomingSdp = async () => {
            const sdpList = await request('api/read-sdp', {
                currentUserId,
            });
            console.log({sdpList});
            await Promise.all(sdpList.map(async ({
                fromUserId,
                sdp,
            }) => {
                await request('api/mark-sdp', {
                    currentUserId,
                    fromUserId,
                });
                if (peerHub.has(fromUserId)) {
                    console.log(`Incoming answer sdp ${fromUserId} ${Date.now()}`, { sdp });
                    const p2p = peerHub.get(fromUserId);
                    p2p.setRemoteSdp(sdp);
                } else {
                    console.log(`Incoming offer sdp ${fromUserId} ${Date.now()}`, { sdp });
                    const p2p = createConnection(fromUserId, false);
                    p2p.setRemoteSdp(sdp);
                }
            }));
        };

        const browseForIncomingIce = async () => {
            const iceList = await request('api/read-ice', {
                currentUserId
            });
            console.log({iceList});
            await Promise.all(iceList.map(async ({
                fromUserId,
                ice,
            }) => {
                await request('api/mark-ice', {
                    currentUserId,
                    fromUserId,
                });
                console.log(`Incoming ice ${fromUserId} ${Date.now()}`, { ice });
                const p2p = peerHub.get(fromUserId);
                p2p.setRemoteIce(ice);
            }));
        };

        const tick = async () => {
            await browseForIncomingSdp();
            await browseForIncomingIce();
        };

        do {
            await tick();
            await sleep(5_000);
        } while (true);

        // button.addEventListener('click', tick);

    })(window);
</script>
```