# Creating a channel for webRTC video chat

Tags: google-app-engine, webrtc, channel, signaling

I've been following the [HTML5rocks webRTC guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#simpleRTCPeerConnectionExample) and I have the Javascript set up as described, however the guide is not clear on how to receive a channelToken, roomKey, and User ID. The guide says,

> "Note that values used in the JavaScript, such as the room variable and
>   the token used by openChannel(), are provided by the Google App Engine
>   app itself: take a look at the [index.html](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/trunk/apprtc/index.html) template in the repository
>   to see what values are added."

Unfortunately the link provided is no good and I'm left with very little information regarding the most essential step in this process. The guide isn't clear about whether or not the Google App Engine is a necessary component and I don't see why it should be. I have searched the web in an attempt to find a more useful source, but I was unsuccessful. I also took a look at the webRTC Demo(https://apprtc.appspot[dot]com), that too was no help seeing that the channel information is generated server side. I feel like I should just be able to make a simple http request to some Google server and then run from there. Any information regarding my problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sam Dutton is right in that the signalling method is up to you. Really, all you're doing is exchanging network information about each peer at the right times, and then the connection is established. I was having trouble with the same thing a while back, but I posted the following question on SO, and got (what I think is) a great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161287/webrtc-video-chat-with-ajax-instead-of-websocket-possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies: the code for this example has been moved to [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/js/apprtc%5C).

(Been meaning to update the article, but haven't had a chance...)

The apprtc.appspot example uses the Channel API on App Engine for signaling, but there are lots of other ways to do this. Signaling mechanisms are not defined by the WebRTC spec. (Note that signaling, which is accomplished via a signaling service, is the exchange of network and media metadata in order to set up a WebRTC 'call': the actual data is communicated directly between peers.)

We ran a [codelab](http://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab) at Google I/O, which describes from start to finish how to build a video chat application that uses Socket.io on Node.js for signaling (it's very simple!) You might want to try that instead.