# {Background} Why is WebRTC always using websockets for signaling?

Tags: rest, websocket, webrtc

I've been working through a bunch of WebRTC examples, and they all require a custom Websocket server for exchanging the signalling data. OTOH, every WebRTC doc states that you can use *anything* for signalling, including carrier pidgeons.

So I've been wondering, just out of curiosity: why isn't signalling usually done using a boring old REST API (or similar)? It's not as if the setup process has realtime requirements, for which using Websockets would make sense...

Comment: Related question (not quite a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161287/webrtc-video-chat-with-ajax-instead-of-websocket-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want the setup process to be *as quick as possible*—usually—and there can be quite a few messages to exchange, especially if you use ICE trickling. Using AJAX you'd have to use repeated polling, which is certainly slower. If that's good enough for you and you see some advantage in doing it that way vs. web sockets, more power to you. But typically you'd want to forward messages to the other peer as soon as you get them, not whenever the other peer happens to poll the server next. And the only practical option to *push* data from the server to the client are web sockets.

You *could* use [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) for the server-to-client push and AJAX for the client-to-server sending… but why, when web sockets already provide duplex communication?

Comment: You could do long polling... it has a few other issues, but it would at least solve the speed issue.

Comment: Sure, you could… but as you say, that has a few other issues. Web sockets are typically the simplest option. Basically, why aren't you using carrier pigeons, even though you *could*…? Well, because it's silly.

Comment: I agree - but that wasn't the question.

Comment: What is the question then? Yes, you *could* use carrier pigeons or long polling or REST… but you typically don't because [see my answer].

Comment: Thanks! Now that I think about this some more, I guess the push feature is the most crucial aspect, because e.g. of ICE renegotiation, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Especially for ICE candidates you may have quite a few messages, and you want to push them as quickly as possible.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind adding that bit to your answer, then I'll accept it. Thanks again!